# Overall client side components

Tags: javascript, html, import, frameworks, web-component

I'm looking for a way to develop a kind of a "parent" framework which will provide sort of a design pattern, so that all existing projects I have could inherit components from, will have the same theme & style and probably same html components. A sort of bootstrap but of a reusable web components to share between different websites.
I thought about modern webcomponents with html imports, but thing is that some of my projects are angular/react and I feel it could be of a hassle to try mixing it all.

I'd like to hear other points of view.

any suggestions on how to approach such task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look to https://vuejs.org/.
Vue.js is a framework including a .vue file extension which is a component extension. You'll have a lot of possibilty with this framework including what you are looking for (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html).

The documentation is really nice :).

Comment: Thanks @thomas i'll surely test vuejs deeper for that purpose

Comment: @Yinon You welcome and trust me, that's a really good framework (like React.js).

Comment: you think it'll be possible to use vuejs' components with other frameworks too?

Comment: @Yinon It depends on what kind of framework you are talking about, but Vue.js can be used with a lot, yes. If you don't want to use Node.js as backend, you can import the standalone of Vue.js link you would do with any JS library ([https://unpkg.com/vue@2.3.4/dist/](https://unpkg.com/vue@2.3.4/dist/)). Here is more information about the standalone and why using it with compiler or not [https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only)